# Wrong configuration xorg-server-1.14.5

Tags: fedora, xorg

I try to install Fedora 18 MR2 - KDE , for that I need to install xorg-server-1.14.5 ...  I download from  http://xorg.freedesktop.org/releases/individual/xserver/xorg-server-1.14.5.tar.gz.

I configure and install ...
./configure --prefix=/usr 
make 
make install 
Also I install dependencies inputproto-2.3.1 and pixman 0.28.0 .

Also I make xorg.conf file which I copy in /etc/X11  folder ...

My configuration is

```
##
## X Config options generated from CED
## x11 conf skeleton
## DriverVer=
##
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Monitor0"
    VendorName  "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName   "Monitor Model"
    Option  "Rotate"    "normal"
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Screen0"
    Device        "IntelEMGD-0"
    Monitor       "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth  24
    SubSection    "Display"
        Depth         32
    EndSubSection
EndSection
# Primary (First/only) display
Section "Device"
    Identifier "IntelEMGD-0"
    Driver     "emgd"
    VendorName "Intel(R) DEG"
    BoardName  "Embedded Graphics"
    BusID      "0:2:0"
    Screen      0
    Option     "PcfVersion"            "1792"
    Option     "ConfigId"              "1"
EndSection
Section "InputDevice"
       Identifier "system-keyboard"
#   MatchIsKeyboard "on"   
        Driver "kbd"
    Option "XkbLayout" "hr"    
    Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
EndSection
Section "InputDevice" 
         Identifier "Mouse0"
         Driver "mouse"
EndSection
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Default Layout"
    Screen 0       "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "system-keyboard" "CoreKeyboard"
  # InputDevice    "DevInputMice" "SendCoreEvents"
EndSection
```

When I use comand /usr/bin/startx  ... fedora restart and after that I can't move with mouse and nothing with keyboard ....

What is wrong ? Could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [fedora package manager](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Package_management_system) for install `xorg`?
Please, give log-file `Xorg.0.log` (maybe path `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`)